# Is it possible to compile Silverlight controls project with Nant?

Tags: xaml, nant

I am attempting to compile my Silverlight control project with Nant without luck. Since my project contains XAML files, I am not sure if Nant is capable of generating the .g.cs files from the XAML file to be compiled into the project. I have come across posts where people suggest using the MsBuild task. Is there a way to avoid using the MsBuild task and compile the project using just Nant? I am not against using the MsBuild task. But would prefer to not use it if possible.

Thank You,
Vish

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand nant currently does not support this out of the box.  Most people are having to shell to msbuild for those portions of the compile step.

However if you know the extra commands for the precompiler, as in what program is used to gen the g.cs files then you could in theory extend nant with a new task to perform that step and then you could get what you need.

May be more work but if you get it to work post it to the community I'm sure they could use it too, if somebody has not done anything for it yet.